# Leaving first row and last row element in python

Tags: python

I have an CSV file , That i am using for plotting graph.
i wanna remove first row and last column from csv file because first row contain naming and last row contain empty spaces.
The program has worked properly once i remove the first and last rows.How can remove the row in this extracted file. what are correction i need to make to run automatically

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

file =open("graph.csv","r+")
reader = csv.reader(file)
TS=[]
TIME=[]
ACT_ANGLE=[]
DES_ANGLE=[]
for line in reader:

       TS.append(line[12])
       TIME.append(line[5])
       ACT_ANGLE.append(line[7])
       DES_ANGLE.append(line[6])

x=TS
z=ACT_ANGLE
#print x
y=DES_ANGLE


plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Time in Sec')
plt.ylabel('Actual angle in degree')
plt.show()
plt.savefig("example.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the first row, you could use the csv.DictReader instead, which will also make your code more readable by allowing you to get the values by name instead of by index. For the last row, something like this would work:

```
for line in [line for line in reader][:-1]:
```

...but that would read the entire file into memory at once to create the list. Since you're already reassigning the values, a simple change to

```
x=TS[:-1]
z=ACT_ANGLE[:-1]
y=DES_ANGLE[:-1]
```

should do, and

```
x=TS[1:][:-1]
z=ACT_ANGLE[1:][:-1]
y=DES_ANGLE[1:][:-1]
```

would strip the first row as well if you don't want to use the dictreader. This leads to more code duplication than the first method, though.